# ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTQ44.png)

I'm trying to list all the "cases". I can't find a syntax error in my code. Really desperate. Trying to find that error for hours. Maybe someone can help?

**Part of my index.html.erb**

```
<tbody>
    <% @cases.each do |case| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= case.first_name %></td>
        <td><%= case.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= case.gender %></td>
        <td><%= case.birthdate %></td>
        <td><%= case.place_of_residence %></td>
        <td><%= case.diagnosis %></td>
        <td><%= case.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= case.confirmed_at %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', case %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_case_path(case) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', case, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**Part of my CaseController**

```
class CasesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_case, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :allowed_to_create, only: [:new, :create]

  # GET /cases
  # GET /cases.json
  def index
    @cases = Case.all
  end

  # GET /cases/1
  # GET /cases/1.json
  def show
    @case = Case.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /cases/new
  def new
    @case = Case.new
  end

  # GET /cases/1/edit
  def edit
  end
```

Comment: Can't see the syntax error. To debug it I would remove the code inside that table and slowly build it up line by line.  If you remove everything inside the loop, but leave the loop there, do you still get the error.  Can you share the whole view template?  I wonder if there is something higher up that could be throwing this table code out of line, a missing `<% end %>` or something, please put in the whole template code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the name of your variable from `case` to something else.  I think Ruby is thinking you're trying to write a switch(called a case in Ruby) statement.

https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/10/ruby-case/